# One flexbox item doesn't align with margin

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have flexbox that has a handful of items. They all look right except for the last one, it expands its bottom to the edge of the div.

[What the flexbox looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9tBNW.png)

As you can see, the last element is expanding to the edge of the container (the black border). I want it to look like the other three. It does the same thing if I only have 3 elements in the container, the last one expands.

Here is my html:

```
<div class="container">
  <a href="" class="list-group-item clearfix">Item</a>
  <a href="" class="list-group-item clearfix">Item</a>
  <a href="" class="list-group-item clearfix">Item</a>
  <a href="" class="list-group-item clearfix">Item</a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  border: solid;
}
a {
  flex-grow: 1;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

I think it is a problem with the bootstrap class I am assigning. If I change my html to:

```
<div class="container">
  <a href="" style="border: solid">Item</a>
  <a href="" style="border: solid">Item</a>
  <a href="" style="border: solid">Item</a>
  <a href="" style="border: solid">Item</a>
</div>
```

[Then the flexboxes align correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o1vrR.png)

Any ideas on how I can fix this, while keeping the bootstrap class? I've tried googling around but haven't found much.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
<div class="container">
        <a href="" style="border: none">Item</a>
        <a href="" style="border: none">Item</a>
        <a href="" style="border: none">Item</a>
        <a href="" style="border: none">Item</a>
      </div>          
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting `border: 0;` should work in your html instead of `border: solid;`